What is the meaning of having a username as the last field of an `/etc/passwd` entry?
In Google Compute Engine VM in /etc/passwd file i see an entry like this one:
root:x:0:0:root:/root:my_logged_in_username_here.
What could that mean? The last field is for user command interpreter as far as i know.

Maybe they have some downstream-patched login that allows root to always use the same login shell as a specific user?

man 5 passwd describes the fields in /etc/passwd. If "Google Compute Engine VM" uses a mutant login, man -a login should help, too.

if shell is missing from /etc/passwd default shell will be used.

Is there a /etc/login.defs? And if yes, is FAKE_SHELL defined there?

The format for /etc/passwd is
name:password:UID:GID:GECOS:directory:shell

so
root:x:0:0:root:/root:my_logged_in_username_here.

my_logged_in_username_here would try to be run as a shell, likely fail and prevent login... it's better to use /usr/sbin/nologin. If you can login as root then there may be a shell named for your username that could enforce some security or some other per user custom thing. There is also FAKE_SHELL from /etc/login.defs which may be in use.
I looked at Alma in GCE and it's normal;
# grep -P ^root: /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash

So it's a product of whatever distribution you are using.
https://linux.die.net/man/5/passwd
https://linux.die.net/man/5/login.defs

FWIW Ubuntu 24.04 LTS...
